# Why Hibernate always select twice?

Tags: hibernate

I have a @OneToMany association, which loaded lazily with @BatchSize(5000). And I see statements like:

```
  select ...
  from ....
  where id in (?,?,?,.....)
```

in the log as expected.

But why does Hibernate always use at least two these select statements, even if number of loaded elements of collection is less that @BatchSize? Why it doesn't load the entire collection just by one select statement?

Comment: Why? I see only performance downsides. If you really need that you can use a FetchProfile

Comment: I just want to understand the reason behind this behavior of Hibernate and if it is possible to change it.

Comment: The in(…) may be limited to a max number of parameters depending on the DB used.